# What is the correct BDD approach for writing cucumber data driven scenarios for very large web forms? External data file or multi-column data tables?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, data-driven

Currently, we are testing a web application that has 15+ forms each with an average of 20 fields. Which way would be better considering performance, maintainability and a BDD-focus?

Comment: For explanation, By multi-column data table, I was referring to: 
a) having data tables with growing number of columns right after a step, or 
b) examples table at the end of a scenario outline having a growing number of columns based on every element you may fill as part of the scenario.

Comment: As Selcuk mentioned, this has nothing to do with BDD. This is just testing, not BDD.

Answer (score 1):

This is the description of DDT : 
Data-driven testing (DDT) is a software testing methodology that is used in the testing of computer software to describe testing done using a table of conditions directly as test inputs and verifiable outputs as well as the process where test environment settings and control are not hard-coded.

I don't know what kind of multi-column data tables you are talking about but it also can be an external source. 
So according to description of DDT it should be an external source whatever it kind be.

Comment: "multi-column data tables" refers to this -> http://www.automationtestinghub.com/cucumber-data-table/